# Change Date Format Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using this code :

```java
final String OLD_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yy";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";

String oldDateString = "16-OCT-19";
String newDateString;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println(newDateString);
```

Is it posible to convert without a conversion to `Date` first so we don't see the format before (`OLD_FORMAT`)?

I have a String that can be any format date. example `"dd-MM-yyyy"`, `"dd-MMM-yyyy"`, `"dd-MMMM-yyyy"`, or anything.
and I want to format into specific format date `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Comment: Short answer, no. If you have multiple input formats, you'll have to try parsing with multiple old formats and see what works, possibly doing it in certain order to avoid ambiguities between the patterns.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't use SimpleDateFormat and Date since they are old and troublesome classes. Use DateTimeFormatter and LocalDate from java.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use the approach that utilizes a list of possible or expected patterns and give each one a `try`, but you should use the most optimized library for it instead of one which is only still alive due to a mass of legacy code referencing it.

**tl;dr**
Your friends for this task (since Java 8) are

- `java.time.LocalDate`
- `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`
- `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`
- `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`

Here's an example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // start with an example String
    String oldDateString = "16-OCT-19";
    
    // build up a list of possible / possibly expected patterns
    List<String> patterns = List.of(
            "dd-MM-uu", "dd-MMM-uu", "dd-MMMM-uu",
            "dd-MM-uuuu", "dd-MMM-uuuu", "dd-MMMM-uuuu"
    );
    
    // then build a formatter for the desired output
    DateTimeFormatter outFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    
    // for each pattern in your list
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        try {
            // build a formatter that
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            // doesn't care about case
                                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                            // uses the current pattern and
                                            .appendPattern(pattern)
                                            // considers the language/locale
                                            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
            // then try to parse the String with that formatter and
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(oldDateString, dtf);
            // print it using the desired output formatter
            System.out.println(localDate.format(outFmt));
            // finally stop the iteration in case of success
            break;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpEx) {
            // build some meaningful statements
            String msg = String.format(
                            "%s !\n  ——> you cannot parse '%s' using pattern %s",
                            dtpEx.getMessage(), oldDateString, pattern);
            // and print it for each parsing fail
            System.err.println(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Try it with different inputs and maybe extend the pattern list.

However, this code example fails for the first pattern in the list but the second one is a match, so this prints

```
Text '16-OCT-19' could not be parsed at index 3 !
  ——> you cannot parse '16-OCT-19' using pattern dd-MM-uu
16/10/2019
```

The remaining patterns are skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do with the inbuilt classes. You can create your own wrapper around it to work it that way.

```
class MultipleDateFormat {
    private List<SimpleDateFormat> formatList;

    MultipleDateFormat(String... formats) {
        formatList = Arrays.asList(formats);
    }

    public Date parse(String dateString) throws Exception {
        for (SimpleDateFormat format : formatList) {
            try {
                return format.parse(dateString);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        throw Exception("String cannot be parsed");
    }
}
```

use this to create the instance for multiple formats.

```
MultipleDateFormat formats = new MultipleDateFormat(format1, format2, . .);
Date date = formats.parse(oldDateString);
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: It was just an example on how to write a wrapper. One can use the java.time classes instead of the above.

Comment: Except all the new developers come along and think - "that's how it should be done" ... and they'd be mislead 

Comment: Approach is ok, library isn't…

Comment: Also note: it is ALSO very bad practice to catch for generic `Exception`. You see, when this method gets passed in stuff like "format-A", null, "format-B" then your code will throw an NPE and you wont ever notice, albeit passing null is probably a bug and not what the user wanted. So that try there should catch exactly that exception type that gets thrown when the formatter pattern doesn't apply.